# IC for magnetic environments

Tags: comparator, counter

I am working on a comparator circuit for converting a small AC signal to a digital (square) signal. The circuit is meant to be used in a strong magnetic environment, so the casing should not have ferromagnetic material such as Fe/Ni etc.

I am using a chip LMH7220MK/NOPB, with Ag plated lead, however when I test with a magnet the chip is magnetically attracted.

Is there any specific supplier or packaging option I can look for to choose my IC (comparator/counter) which are made of non magnetic material?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ask the vendor. If they don't have any non-ferrous leadframes, you may have to look at unbonded dice - if there are any ceramic hybrid manufacturers left, they can package the die onto a hybrid to your specification.

Comment: Why will a ferrous leadframe be a problem for your application?

Comment: You might want to consider how the circuits for [magnetic resonance imaging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging) are built.  The circuits are certainly in use in a strongly magnetic environment, but I've never read that they have to use special non-magnetic parts.

Comment: @JRE I'm guessing they are located away from the strongest field region; in addition there may be mu-metal shielding involved (strongly bolted down!)

Comment: @BrianDrummond:  That's why Shimul Saha should look into how its done there.  Placement and shielding.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable comments. @Brian Drummond, I asked the local vendors (Mouser), they could not offer an alternative parts. How easy it is to get an unbounded dice? Best Regards - Shimul

Comment: @JRE and Andy aka, there can be small magnetic material in the chip if they are placed away from the magnet. My device intended to be at the heart of the MRI scanner, so it would feel the strongest force and I want to avoid the risk of being pulled away to the magnet.

Comment: Unbonded dice? Check with the manufacturer. Some make it easier than others; see http://www.ti.com/die-wafer-services/overview.html for one example. (apparently TI is a source for your part so you may be lucky)

Comment: Thanks @Brian Drummond. I will explore TI, wonder this might effect the price!